# PostgreSQL: Calculate elapsed hours across time change

Tags: postgresql, time

How can I calculate the number of hours between two times, taking into account the change from standard to daylight savings time between them?

I need to determine which crew is working in my customer's plant.  There are four possibilities, changing in a known order from one to the next every four days, so the crew pattern recurs every 16 days.  I had planned to store a reference time in my database.  To calculate the crew, I would calculate the elapsed hours between the reference time and the current time, modulo it by 384, and use crew A if the result is below 96, crew B for 96-192, and so on.

I am pretty sure that in the spring, when an hour is repeated at the time change, the crew shift is 13 hours long, and in the fall, the crew shift is only 11 hours long.  My scheme, at least if it relied on timestamp with time zone objects, would be wrong for an hour every shift for half the year.

Thank you.

Comment: "*My scheme, at least if it relied on timestamp with time zone objects, would be wrong*" - why do you think that? a `timestamp WITH time zone` will take DST changes into account and subtracting one from the other should give you correct results

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  To get a valid test, I had to change my computer's time, first to the day before the time change and then to the day after.  When I did that, my original idea worked.